# Azure media services real-time livestream

Tags: video-streaming, real-time, rtmp, live-streaming, azure-media-services

Is it possible to set up a *live stream* in Azure media services that is effectively live, i.e. meets real-time requirements? I would like to achieve a maximum *latency of 1 to 2 seconds*.

That must be possible somehow, since video chat platforms, including MS Teams, can also stream video in real time. In any case, the delay is small enough so that you don't have to wait 25 seconds for your conversation partner.

Has anyone ever implemented something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Media Services is not a real time chat platform.  It was built as a broadcast architecture capable of streaming to thousands or tens of thousands of clients.  That architecture is different than a real time architecture.  Media Services scales to very large audiences by building in buffers, adding the capability of using a CDN to cache content, and uses codecs that are meant for high quality instead of speed.  Microsoft Teams is not built in the same way.  It is built for that real time communication and is a product intended for that.  Media Services does have settings to reduce the broadcast delay, but not to 1 second.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/live-event-latency-reference for more info.

Comment: Thx for the fast response! Sadly on the page I have also come across, but I had hope that something could be done :D

I also came across Azure communication services. Do you know about it? And if so, do you think it's possible to achieve the low latencies with it?

Comment: Azure Communication Services could definitely be used.  It actually uses the Teams backend.  Think of it as the capabilities of Teams for chat / video / etc. but without the Teams front end.